# Remove app title and icon overlay on Google Glass app

Tags: google-glass

I've just developed my first Google Glass app (Android Studio) and I was hoping you all might help me work through a problem.  I initially developed the app for Android and made the necessary modifications to be able to target Glass (a few updates to the manifest and a few new xml files).  The app installs and runs just fine on Glass, with the exception of one quirk: the app icon and title are overlaying the top ~20% of the Glass display, like a title-bar banner.

Is there something that needs to be added/subtracted from a typical android development environment to disable this overlay?

Sorry I don't have a screenshot.  I can try to figure out how to capture one on Glass if it helps.

Comment: What kind of `Activity` are you using ? It seems that you're using an Activity that already contains ActionBar/Toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

I got to the bottom of if.
[Remove app title bar android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23255373/remove-app-title-bar-android)

I failed to put the **android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"**  declaration in the correct place in the manifest.

Thank you.