# Unable to remove Title bar from app

Tags: android

I am using `AppTheme.NoActionBar`. I am trying to remove title bar from app.

Here what i have already tried.

Tried settings `android:theme="@style/Theme.NoTitleBar"` this gives me error `cannot resolve symbol`

Tried adding `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` in onCreate method before setting `ContentView` it doesn't affect anything

Here are the post i posts i already tried

[How to hide the title bar for an Activity in XML with existing custom theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591036/how-to-hide-the-title-bar-for-an-activity-in-xml-with-existing-custom-theme)

[Remove app title bar android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23255373/remove-app-title-bar-android)

What i am trying to do is i am creating a custom UI and want the app full screen(want to show notification bar).

Also my app is targeted for Api level 10 and above

**Update**
Here are few more things i tried https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113175/discussion-between-arthur-leao-and-akash-kumar suggested by @ArhturLeao

**Update 2**

Tried `@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar` on a new sample project worked as expected(had to extened Activity class instead of AppCompactActivity class)

Tried same with project i am having issue and it still shows Blank TitleBar.

Here is the project i am having trouble with https://github.com/skywebdeveloper/Tikona-Session-Manager/tree/design

**Update 3 **

`onCreate` Method

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager());

        popupLoader = new ProgressDialog(this);

        url = getSharedPreferences("url", MODE_PRIVATE);
        sessionPreference = getSharedPreferences("session", MODE_PRIVATE);

        sessionStart = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sessionStartValue);
        sessionDuration = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sessionDurationValue);
        sessionUsage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sessionUsageValue);


        logout = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        logout.setMessage("Are you sure you want logout?").setTitle("Confirm Logout");
        logout.setPositiveButton("Logout", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //Call logout uri
                logout();
            }
        });
        logout.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //Do nothing
            }
        });

        logout.create();

        //fetchSessionDetails();
        getURLs();

    }
```

> style.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->

        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

Comment: Did you make custom title bar(custom UI)?

Comment: @Masum I haven't created my custom Ui yet. My app used Default App theme till now. But now i need a custom UI. I am still new to Designing android apps. Just trying to tweek things.

Comment: have you tried http://stackoverflow.com/a/25365193/3702862 ?

Comment: @FabCoder just tried not working. TitleBar is still shown.

Comment: If you don't want title bar then why are you adding **Toolbar** in your activity?

Comment: @rom4ek Can you explain why I am able to show the Toolbar without hiding the ActionBar explicitly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've explored your project and found your problem: by **style** you are of course removing `ActionBar`, but you've forgot that you have a **Toolbar** in your `activity_main.xml`, and more than that you are setting it as a default `ActionBar` for your `Activity` by next code:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Then of course you will have your `ActionBar` always appearing :) So all you need is just to add `getSupportActionBar().hide();` in activities which you want to be fullscreen:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

And it should work as expected.

Comment: Thanx it worked. Why do i have two xml layout named activity and content. I do all the work in content layout.

Comment: Cause in `activity_main.xml` you have an `AppBarLayout`  + `include`  and that `include` is including your `content_main` exactly. So it was done to divide content and appbar:)

Answer (score 1):

Just add these to your style:

```
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

Here is a complete example:

**styles.xml**

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

I've just created a new project using the "Blank Activity" template and added the two lines to the style - everything else is using the default configuration.

Comment: Not Working... Title bar is still shown. These example work perfectly fine with new sample project i created. But not working with the current project i am working on. Don't know the reason.

Comment: @AkashKumar, could you post your style and the Activity (or at least the onCreate method)? I'll try to figure out what is going wrong.

Comment: This is repo of the project i am having issue with https://github.com/skywebdeveloper/Tikona-Session-Manager/tree/design

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it up.

Comment: @AkashKumar, the Tikona project is actually using a NoActionBar. Instead the activity's layout contains a Toolbar, which is used as an ActionBar. You can't remove it via the styles, because the View is added from the layout. If you want to remove it look for the android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout and the android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar elements in the activity_main.xml. You can either hide them (visibility: gone) or remove them completely (the end result will be a lot cleaner, but you'll have to remove any code references to them too).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Add

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

To your onCreate Method, after super.onCreate and before setContentView

Comment: App crash with `java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.`

Comment: One question: when you added this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

Where did you inserted it?

Comment: And try adding android:theme="@style/AppTheme" to your android manifest, below <application

Comment: In my `MainActivity` Class inside `onCreate` method before `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

Also tried adding `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"` inside Application attribute

Comment: Does it still crash with java.lang.IllegalStateException?

Comment: Don't know why you're getting these errors. Let's try ad different aproach, i edited  my response. Delete these changes we tried.

Comment: Should i set my theme back to AppCompact or continue with same

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113175/discussion-between-arthur-leao-and-akash-kumar).

Answer (score 0):

This code is working for me and doesnt have a App Bar

I had replaced it with a Toolbar.

Find out what you are missing.

**I think you are not applying your AppTheme.NoActionBar to your MainActivity in Manifest.**

**MainActivity.java**

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 EditText editUsername,editPassword;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
       toolbar.setTitle("Login");
       setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

       editUsername=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
       editPassword=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);


     }
   }
```

**styles.xml**

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"  
     parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="com.example.storelist" >

 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>

 </manifest>
```

Comment: Still not working TitleBar is still shown. If i use this code with new project it work fine. But with my current project its not working. 
This is the repo of the project i am having issue with https://github.com/skywebdeveloper/Tikona-Session-Manager/tree/design

Comment: Can you try File->Invalidate Caches/Restart Option -> Invalidate and Restart and then check your app