# @android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar does not fully work

Tags: android

For my app I want to hide fully the title bar (or ActionBar?!?). With @android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar I am able to hide it but if the user want swipes two times down he can get the title bar. Is there any other possibility to hide (or remove) this bar? Or can the user forbit the bar in the settings of the system?

@Admin: This is not a duplicate to [Hide Notification bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4222713/hide-notification-bar) or [Remove app title bar android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23255373/remove-app-title-bar-android). In this solution the user has access to this bar after he swiped down two times